# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#<Object>' while angular ssr build

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I got some error while build my angular ssr project. check the below screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0pYR.png)

Error not belons to project folder, Can anyonr please help.

What is actual reason of this error, is this due to angulat cli?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.